# android switch user programmatically

Tags: android, switch-user

I'm trying to create an app that runs the `switch-user` command.
is there any API for switch-user command ?

is it possible to switch users from android application (assuming I've multiple users set)?

Comment: I doubt its possible, but in any case Stack Overflow is not a place for such questions.

Comment: IMHO SO is the right place for this question

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks. can you please explain why it's not the place? (so i will know better in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For switching user there is no direct api, U have manually maintain the session of each user. The session implementation logic upto u.